# How to cite both editions of a book

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style, apa6, jabref

I generally use APA style. But, the style might not be relevant here (I don't know).

I have seen people citing like this: Chomsky1957[2002] where the [2002] part refers to the 2nd edition of the book while the 1957 part is the first edition.

```
@Book{Chomsky2002S,
author = {Chomsky, Noam}, 
title = {Syntactic structures}, 
publisher = {Mouton de Gruyter}, 
address = {Berlin; New York}, 
year = {2002}, 
edition = {2},
```

This is obviously the entry for the second edition of the book. For historical reasons, I also need to mention (indicate) in the text that this is the same book to the 1957 classic.

1) Am I supposed to have both editions as separate entries in my bibtex library, or any better way of linking?
2) Am I supposed to  insert each as  separate references in the **Reference** section?

Comment: Since you are trying to follow APA guidelines, a natural follow-up quesstion is: What, if anything, do these guidelines say? Put differently, you should be consulting the 6th (or, since a short while ago, 7th) edition of the guidelines, and not rely on opinions of random people on the Internet. If the guidelines have anything to say regarding the points you raise, you should follow these guidelines punctiliously. Conversely, if they're silent, just do whatever feels appropriate.

Comment: According to the APA blog, you have *Chomsky, 1957/2002* in the text, and the 2002 work in the bibliography with the note *Original work published 1957* in the bibliography. This is what `biblatex-apa` gives me if I set `origdate=1957`. But (1) as Mico points out it's not a TeX question and (2) a second edition is not a reprint if the text is revised, of course.

Comment: I think this as bibtex question because I don't know if it has a field, say, for *origdate* that you are putting the original date in. But, thank you for the explanation. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Biblatex with Biber should do the trick with that type of file including some sort of crossref:

```
@book{texttocite,
title={Title},
author={Author},
year={Year},
publisher={Publisher},
related={originaltext},
relatedstring={See :},
}

@book{originaltext,
title={Title},
author={Author},
booktitle={Booktitle},
publisher={Publisher},
year={Year}
}
```

With that you can cite 'texttocite' and it will cite both in you bibliography in the form "Citation" See : "Original text".

That works fine to cite translations as well.

Thus if you use the apa style it will be compliant, and if you want to switch styles it will still work fine.

Comment: This is the type of trick I have been looking for.But, the "related" field is not part of the list of fields in the Bibtex; and, I really don't get any effect when I add that field. I use crossref, but for "incollection" field to get the extra fields from the collection work. Can you elaborate how to use this field?

Comment: You have to use Biblatex (https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) instead of Bibtex. It's a more powerful solution for biblios and you don't have to worry about complexity, once it's set up it runs as smooth as Bibtex.  CrossRef is a hardcoded cross-referencing item form bibtex, it has a unique meaning which is complicated to edit. With the "related" field, you can do whatever you want to do. I started to use it to cite some american texts translated into french into a collected edition, something like Author (1955) Original, infos Trad dans. Text  In  : Book, editor, (1979).

Comment: The general idea is that the 'related' field is a macro that merges two bib entries accordingly to your citation style. The 'relatedstring' is just a customizable token that goes inbetween so everything is possible :)

Comment: I don't use  Biblatex because it is slower. I am now using the "note" filed to mention the original.

Comment: It's a way to do that, I think you still can manually define a `\relatedcite{}` command which would create a customized citation in order to nest them juste like the `related` field of biblatex but it's more of a customization that a general solution.

Comment: @RémiZin is there a way to cite different page numbers in the two different entries? For instance, the first might have paragraph numbers in the original and the related text which is a reprint would have page numbers.

Comment: Of course, you just have to do multiple bibtex entries, the first "textocite" would refer to some pages and a "textocitebis" would refer to other ones.

Comment: Or since they are different entries they are basically independant so you can do basically whatever you want ;)